# What does this sentence mean and what is 'general furniture'?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> The general furniture was profuse, comfortless, antique, and tattered.

What is general furniture?

What does profuse mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is general furniture?

I think it may simply mean "miscellaneous furniture" or "various furnishings". Viewing https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=general+furniture&year_start=1700 it seems that the usage of the term peaked around the time Poe wrote the line. Looking at some of the references, it does not seem like "general furniture" is a set term, so I suspect that it's merely the case that the usage of *general* that permits the phrase was popular around that time. (c.f. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=general+furniture,general+clothing&year_start=1700 )

> What does profuse mean in this sentence?

Ornate, lavish. Though we mostly use "profuse" to describe over-the-top apologies, it used to allow for over-the-top *whatever*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: I would interpret 'profuse' as meaning 'plentiful' or 'present in large amounts'.

Comment: Though the primary meaning of *profuse* is "plentiful," I find it harder to understand Poe's meaning here with that definition. You're suggesting the idea is that the room is crowded with furniture?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Common in  the 19th century.